# UNIX bash if command error

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a simple flag variable in an UNIX shell script so that during downtime I can turn off certain processing.

When I do an if statement, keep getting a command not found error.

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

hold=false

if [$hold = false]
then
  echo "$hold" > ADW_UNIX.dat
fi

exit 0
```

Error:

```
13:03:05 # ./ADW_UNIX.script
./ADW_UNIX.script: line 5: [false: command not found
```

Comment: You need spaces around `[` and `]` (and add quotes to make everybody happy): `if [ "$hold" = false ]`

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ will catch this (and many other common errors).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your complete requirement as you haven't thrown light on same, so trying to fix your script itself.

```
#!/bin/bash    
hold="false"    
if [[ "$hold" == "false" ]]
then
  echo "$hold" > ADW_UNIX.dat
fi
exit 0
```